# Cant find the php-fpm config

Tags: centos5, php-fpm

I cant find the php-fpm config file on my server.
I tried to make an `php-fpm.conf` file in `/etc/php.d/` folder, but it doesn't get included.

Its not in these locations either: `/etc/php-fpm.conf` file or `/etc/php-fpm.d`

Output of `php -v`

```
-bash-3.2# php -v
PHP 5.4.10 (cli) (built: Dec 19 2012 11:25:26) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

The OS on the server: CentOs 5.
I'm running nginx+php-fpm.

Any idea where it could be, or how I can make one an get it included?

Some output of `php -i`: (i replaced system with x)

```
-bash-3.2# php -i
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.4.10

System => x
Build Date => Dec 19 2012 11:24:59
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php.d/apc.ini,
/etc/php.d/bbcode.ini,
/etc/php.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/dom.ini,
/etc/php.d/fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php.d/igbinary.ini,
/etc/php.d/json.ini,
/etc/php.d/mbstring.ini,
/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php.d/memcache.ini,
/etc/php.d/memcached.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php.d/pdo_sqlite.ini,
/etc/php.d/phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/wddx.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php.d/xsl.ini,
/etc/php.d/zip.ini

PHP API => 20100412
PHP Extension => 20100525
Zend Extension => 220100525
Zend Extension Build => API220100525,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20100525,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => disabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => disabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, sslv2, tls
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, mcrypt.*, mdecrypt.*

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Where did you get PHP from?

Comment: CentOs 5 ?   Seriously ? This one is dead for years...

Answer (score 1):

I just reinstalled php-fpm with

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-fpm
```

For some reason it works now.. The config files are made, and php is using FPM.

Answer (score 0):

php5-fpm configuration file is normally /etc/php5. There there are configurations for the php5-fpm, cli and common modules. [ not sure if that applies to RH kind of os, because that's where i find them on debian kind ]

Comment: The folder /etc/php5 doesnt exists. I have `/etc/php.d` and `/etc/php-zts.d`. None of them have the fpm config.